# Stop PHP Pagination for certain results

Tags: php, pagination

I have a page that has a list of Youtube videos.  I use an array as below then later in the page I use some other functions to display the title and screen grab of the video down the page.  This way I just have to add a new vidoe to the list below and it grabs all the correct info from YouTube:

```
//exampleX is a youtube video code
$videolist = array(
"example1",
"example2",
"example3",
"example4",
"example5"
);
```

Over time this list has grown to the point where I need to add some automatic pagination for the videos as the list continues to grow.  I've done that once before so I think I can handle that part.

However the customer has some videos that need to stay together on the same page no matter what.  I'm not sure how to handle that part.

Any thoughts on this would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: Have a look into "bin packing" algorithms.  The videos that need to be on the same page just need to be "packed into the same bin".  The size of the bin would be the number of videos per page.

Comment: Might be time to think about an object for your 'Videos'  Could store additional attributes.  Like whatever this attribute that suggest they "need to stay together" is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a simple extension of what you already have without needing too much modification, consider making your array of videos multidimensional, with a key that indicates it should be kept together. When paginating them, if you encounter one having `keeptogether => TRUE` at the end of your page's list, rather than breaking, continue looping output until you reach the next `keeptogether => FALSE`.  (I would also build in the ability to omit the `keeptogether` key as equivalent to a `FALSE` value).

```
$videolist = array(
  array("title" => "example1", "keeptogether" => FALSE),  
  array("title" => "example2", "keeptogether" => FALSE),
  array("title" => "example3", "keeptogether" => TRUE),
  array("title" => "example4", "keeptogether" => TRUE),
  array("title" => "example5" "keeptogether" => FALSE)
);
```

If you need it to work more elegantly when a `keeptogether => TRUE` occurs at the end of a page and it should instead break to the next page before continuing (so the current page doesn't get too long), consider a simple algorithm like:

```
# Pseudocode:
# Encountering a keeptogether == TRUE when 2 from the end of a normal page length:
if current_page_counter < (num_per_page - 2) and keeptogether == TRUE
  break_to_next_page
else
  loop_until keeptogether == FALSE
```

Comment: Good idea!  I like this method because, as you said, it doesn't modify my existing process too heavily.  I will work on this method.  Thanks!

Comment: I found one pitfall...not a problem for my situation but for those looking at this.  If 1 & 2 should be together and 3 & 4 should be together, but those are 2 different groups, its going to keep them grouped on one page.  If using this method may want to make another element for a "BREAKOK" at the end of a group.  Just a thought...still...it's working great for me.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps in your list you can sort them by groups and paginate by group. Most groups would only  have one video, but those ones which need videos together would have multiple videos. Like so:

```
$videolist = array(
    "group1" => array("example1")
    "group2" => array("example2", "example3"),
    "group3" => array("example4"),
    "group4" => array("example5"),
);
```

So instead of paginating by video, you paginate by group and usually a group has one video, but it could have more than one.

If you use a database for storing these as well you can replicate this structure there.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a multi-dimensional array to store the videos? Each element of the `$videolist` array would contain an array of videos. Most of these would only have one element, but ones which need to be grouped together would be in the same array, like so:

```
$videolist = array(
    array("example1"),
    array("example2"),
    array("example3", "example4"),
    array("example5")
);
```

Then, when displaying the videos, you can do something like this:

```
$Offset = 1;
$PerPage = 2;
$Count = 0; $Displayed = 0;
foreach ($videolist as $videoarray) {
    foreach ($videoarray as $video) {
        $Count++;
        if ($Count <= $Offset) continue;

        $Displayed++;
        // Display Video
    }

    if ($Displayed >= $PerPage) break;
}
```

This way, the page doesn't end until the end of a current group.

You can also change it, so you do a `count()` of `$videoarray` before iterating over it and break if it would push the total over `$PerPage`